# How to align elements in CKEditor dialog

Tags: ckeditor

I have text field with button in my CKEditor dialog:

```
{
    type: 'hbox',
    id: 'search',
    children: [ 
        {
            type: 'text',
            id: 'searchText',
            label: 'Search something'
        },
        {
            id: 'searchButton',
            type: 'button',
            label: 'Search',
            onClick: function() {
                alert("o.O");
            }
        }
    ]    
}
```

Problem is, that `searchButton` is aligned with text field's label instead of text field itself. I tried to add `align` property to `hbox` and to the button too (with values `bottom` and `center`), but nothing happend.

How can I have that button aligned in the same line as text field?

Answer (score 2):

I faced same problem too.I have got ride of this problem by applying style property.

```
{
    type : 'button',
    id : 'searchButton',
    label : 'Search',
    style : 'margin-top:15px;',        
}
```